# How can I change the scrip name in URL while executing the code in python

Tags: python

I have the `python` code which gives me the `VWAP` value for the derivative script.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=INFY&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=30MAY2019&type=-&strike=-')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#responseDiv').text.strip())
vwap = data['data'][0]['vwap']
print(vwap)
```

There is a pattern for URL where just the name of the underlying changes.
For example in given 2 URLs:

```
https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=RELIANCE&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=30MAY2019&type=-&strike=-

https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=INFY&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=30MAY2019&type=-&strike=-
```

What can be the code where the program asks for input as the script name and the script name changes in the URL?

Comment: url is string so you can use any string function - ie. `"underlying={}...".format("other_text")`. You can change order of parameters in url and put `underlying=` and the end and concatenate value `"https://...&underlying=" + "other_text"`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `requests.get(...)` is a string and you can manipulate it just like a string. For this case, I suggest using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) (or you can also use `f-strings`).

```
base_url = 'https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying={}&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=30MAY2019&type=-&strike=-'
underlying_list = ['RELIANCE', 'INFY']

for underlying in underlying_list:
    url = base_url.format(underlying)
    print(url)
    resp = requests.get(url)
    ...
```

This approach would also allow you to use more parameters if there are other parts of the URL that need to be different for each call; you simply add more parameters to the `.format()` call (and modify `base_url` accordingly to accept those new parameters).

Comment: Thank a lot @ Ralf